# Using Eclipse text editor background color to differentiate lines

Tags: eclipse

I am an android developer and I am trying to increase the readability of my source code when using Eclipse.  What I am trying to do (and can't figure it out) is change the preferences so that two background colors are used:  For example, the odd numbered lines have a background color of White and the even numbered lines have a background color of Gray.  This makes it very easy to separate lines when browsing code quickly.

The best example I can give you can be found here: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/thread/android-thread-example/

Just scroll down to the code and you'll see what I mean.

I am not sure this is even possible in Eclipse.  If not it would be great to know that so I could stop looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, even with latest version.
You could use a plugin to 'theme' your editor like eclipsecolorthemes ... but even with theme, there is no alternate row color.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll stop looking and start on a new feature request.  This type of feature could definitely help someone with vision issues.